# Popup Malware “openadserving.com”

Tags: command-line, hosts, malware

can someone help me please?!

When I'm using **Chrome** (or **Fire Fox**) I'm getting fullscreen popup advertising even on sites that I am certain do not have it. I see the web site it is trying to load is "`www.openadserving.com`" in the status bar.

So i looked on this forum and I saw a same problem.. So i tried to fix it my self true Terminal.. But it doesn't work.. This was an answer from Sadi.. ([Chrome Popup Malware "openadserving.com"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257034/chrome-popup-malware-openadserving-com))

> You haven't provided sufficient information to identify the problem
>   accurately, but the following suggestions may help to identify or even
>   hopefully solve it:
>
> You can open your hosts file (enter this command in terminal: `sudo
>   gedit /etc/hosts`) and enter this line at the bottom: `127.0.0.1
>   www.openadserving.com` As this will prevent all connection between
>   this site and your computer after restart, this might solve your
>   problem or if it doesn't, then;
>
> You can try a program like Net Activity Viewer to see a list of sites
>   your browser is being connected, and add all undesirable addresses
>   there as in the step 1.
>
> You can try using a utility like hostsblock to prevent connection to
>   such sites in general. (This utility can be downloaded and manually
>   installed from ArchLinux repositories with just one minor
>   modification, replacing pathname `/etc/rc.d` with `/etc/init.d` in
>   these files: hostsblock.sh, hostsblock-urlcheck.sh and rc.conf)

I did the first step but it doesn't work... i get this in my screen

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Anna:~ atoma92$ sudo gedit /etc/hosts Password: sudo: gedit: command not found
```

Please help me:(

Comment: You don't need to use `gedit` if you don't have it installed, just use any text editor, even `nano`, so you could do `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Comment: Wow, thanks! And after I added the 127.0.0.1 www.openadserving.com line at the bottom, I just close terminal?

Comment: I originally closed your question, but upon consideration I'll leave it open. Please post an answer though, since your *real* problem was the missing gedit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you installed a rogue extension for Chrome. Could you enter `chrome://extensions/` in the address bar of Chrome and look what extensions are installed? Try disabling all of them. (Or at least the ones that seem strange to you.) Maybe that fixes the behavior. If it doesn't, try reinstalling Chrome as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257194/21008).